# can i add youtube link in iOS app description

Tags: ios, youtube, app-store

My app meta data was rejected by apple. They are asking that what is the purpose of this app?. I replied to the app review team with video attachments. My app status is currently " In Review ".I am thinking add youtube video link for my in description. My doubt is apple is allow to keep the youtube video link in description and can i add the extra data to the description at the app status is In Review.

Comment: Better directly try it out and see for yourself rather than waiting here for an answer.

Comment: no need Man, you are already explain for this  "They are asking that what is the purpose of this app" ?, clearly , in my knowledge no need of extra words,otherwise ur choice